# Entity framework 4.1 - inheritance with foreign key on same column

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I do this to create several child classes on a same table based on TPH with discriminator filter.

```
public class TraceBilletStation : Trace
{
    [UserVisible(Ordre = 6)]
    public BilletStation BilletStationnement { get; set; }
}

public class TraceBilletStationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<TraceBilletStation>
{
    public TraceBilletStationMap()
    {
        this.HasOptional(p => p.BilletStationnement).WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("TRA_CONCEPT_ID_INFO"));
    }
}
```

It works fine with one child, but I need more, so I add this :

```
public class TraceAcheteur : Trace
{
    [UserVisible(Ordre = 6)]
    public Acheteur Acheteur { get; set; }
}


public class TraceAcheteurMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<TraceAcheteur>
{
    public TraceAcheteurMap()
    {
        this.HasOptional(p => p.Acheteur).WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("TRA_CONCEPT_ID_INFO"));
    }
}
```

and there I get a `MetadataException` saying that the property "TRA_CONCEPT_ID_INFO" has already been defined.

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot map any column twice. You must use another column for your second relation or you must use only single relation defined in the base class.